# Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'UIColor'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class MovingGround : SKSpriteNode {

    let MovingGroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "MovingGround")

    init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: nil, size:CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height))
        anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        position = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)
        zPosition = 1
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

I keep getting an error on `color: nil`, how can I change it?

Comment: Supply a UIColor instance instead of nil ?

Comment: By the way, `size` is a size. Pulling it apart into its width and height and putting it back together thru CGSizeMake is silly.

Answer (score 3):

As the error message tells you, `nil` is not a color. If you are going to call `init(texture:color:size:)` you must supply an actual color. I suggest white, which is the default.

```
super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size:size)
```